# How should I store geo coordinates in mongoid to be used with sunspot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, sunspot

I have a mongoid RoR app that is using sunspot for search.

How should I store the coordinates in mongoid documents and make them searchable?

Answer (score 1):

Just store them in an array, index the field, and query with geo spatial methods seen here:
http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html#symbol

For example:

```
class Doc
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :location, type: Array
  index({ location: "2d" }, { min: -200, max: 200 })
end
```

Call like:
`Doc.within_circle(location: ...)`

Comment: This doesn't use sunspot for searching.